# What's the difference between 魔{ま} and 鬼{おに}?

Tags: meaning, kanji

Both seem to mean "demon". Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

悪魔【あくま】 is the word which corresponds to the English word *demon*. For example [Belphegor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belphegor) is a typical 悪魔.

魔 by itself sometimes refers to 悪魔, but it's a more general kanji which means *evil* or *evil things*. It includes Western-style 悪魔, Japanese evil entities like [閻魔](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yama), and monsters in general.

In modern usage, 鬼 usually refers to one certain type of Japanese monster, which has two horns and colorful (mainly red) skin. Here's the result of Google Image Search:

[image: Oni]

The kanji 鬼 probably used to refer to ghosts and demons in general (Wikipedia says 鬼 means *ghost* in Chinese), and serious Buddhists may have another definition I'm not familiar with. But it's safe to think it only refers to this stereotyped 鬼 today, at least among ordinary people.